# TensorFlow 2.0: create replica-local variable under MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm implementing Memory Transformer and I need to keep the `memory` between calls to the model. I've tried to use `tf.Variable` for this task and it works perfectly on a single GPU.

But under MirroredStrategy on multiple GPUs this approach fails because mirrored strategy wants to synchronize the variables written on multiple replicas. Which is not needed in my case, I need to create a personal set of memory variables on each 'tower' like in TransformerXL implementation.

I think I can use `with tf.device():` to create those variables but I'm not sure how to get current replica's device inside `build` method.